# Struggling with the Primereact DataView component in a redux state managed Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, primereact

I am trying to utililise the Primereact DataView and the problem is that my data is loaded from the backend using an action. The following is my code and will explain my objective latter.

```
 export const getFinishedProjects = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get(finishedProjectsURL)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_FINISHED_PROJECTS,
                payload: res.data
            });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

componentDidMount() {
            this.props.getFinishedProjects();
        }  
  
<div className="dataview-demo">
                <div className="card">
                    <DataView 
                        value={this.props.finishedprojects} 
                        layout={this.state.layout} 
                        header={header}
                        lazy
                        itemTemplate={this.itemTemplate} 
                        paginator 
                        paginatorPosition={'both'} 
                        rows={this.rows}
                        totalRecords={this.state.totalRecords} 
                        first={this.state.first}  
                    />
                </div>
            </div>

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
   finishedprojects : state.finishedprojects.finishedprojects
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getFinishedProjects} ) (FinishedProjects);
```

Now here is the problem now in the Documentation there are these two functions I assume are for loading data

```
 componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.productService.getProducts().then(data => {
                this.datasource = data;
                this.setState({
                    totalRecords: data.length,
                    products: this.datasource.slice(0, this.rows),
                    loading: false
                });
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    onPage(event) {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        });

        //imitate delay of a backend call
        setTimeout(() => {
            const startIndex = event.first;
            const endIndex = event.first + this.rows;

            this.setState({
                first: startIndex,
                products: this.datasource.slice(startIndex, endIndex),
                loading: false
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
```

With my approach I seem to get this error: Error: DataViewItem(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

My assumption is that maybe it has something to do with how I am loading data from backend. If thats the case may someone kindly help on how do I imitate those documentation like functions and render data in the DataView. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the paginator that comes with PrimeReact is the one causing the problem in my case. So I had paginator={false} and the Dataview started working again. I'm still in the process of debugging it, but in the meantime you can test if your data is working properly by disabling the paginator and if the Dataview doesn't work then your data might not be in the correct format because the DataView expects an array of objects.

Comment: thanks at Thabang, well its a paginator issue too from my part,,, but it goes deeper because its displaying now with the paginator ={true} but the thing is I cant seem to click and navigate to the next page,,, it just gives an empty page and in seconds starts to yell at me